# Audio Streamer works on iPad but not on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, audio-streaming

I have created an app which streams audio from a webserver.

The music player in the app works fine if it is installed:

- As iPhone app on iPad 2
- In iPhone Simulator

But it does not work on iPhone 3G device.

What could be wrong?

**Just to give you a background:**

I have two views. One view (MainView) is suppose to play song "ABC". When user clicks another view (Detail View), it should pause "ABC" and should start song "XYZ".

**Here's what happens on:**

**iPhone Device:** When we go to Detail View, it pauses songs "ABC", but after few seconds, it again starts "ABC" instead of "XYZ".

**iPhone Simulator & iPhone app on iPad:** When we go to Detail View, it pauses song "ABC" and plays "XYZ". When we switch back to MainView it again starts playing "ABC" from where it left off.

It looks like problem with Net connectivity but if that is the case then it should not play "ABC" also.

Can you please suggest what could be wrong?

Thanks!

**Here the code that I used for Audio Streamer:**

```
- (void)createStreamer
{
NSLog(@"str_audio url:%@",str_AudioUrl);

if (streamer)
{
    return;
}
NSLog(@"create stremer %d",selectedIndex);
//[self destroyStreamer];

NSString *escapedValue = [(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(nil,//Here pass the string of url
                                                                              (CFStringRef)str_AudioUrl,
                                                                              //  (CFStringRef)downloadSourceField.text,
                                                                              NULL,NULL,kCFStringEncodingUTF8)autorelease];

//str_AudioUrl is my string where data come.


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedValue];
streamer = [[AudioStreamer alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSLog(@"Streamer : %@",streamer);




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found bug with Audiostreamer class. Solution is found in this link:

https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer/issues/26

Hope this helps someone facing similar problem.